# promise-queue processing out of order

Tags: javascript, promise, queue

I am experimenting with what I believe is a basic use case of [promise-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-queue)

```
var Queue = require("promise-queue")
let queue = new Queue();

//add first item to queue
queue.add(() => {
console.log('start 1');
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('finished processing');
          resolve();
        },
        5000);
    });
});

//add second item to queue
queue.add(() => { console.log('start 2'); });
```

results in the output:

```
>start 1
>start 2
>finished processing
```

The second item starts before the first item is completed. What am i missing?

Try this code sample [runkit](https://runkit.com/wallaceturner/59a113705fafee001264c52f)

Comment: You are noticing the effects of the callstack and queue which make JavaScript very special. Your code executes the entire file in about 20ms. The JS interpretter hits line 5 and logs 1, then loads the promise into the queue, then executes 'start 2' immediately after, then after 5 seconds, the promise is resolved.

Comment: I'm looking at your code now, but I don't know how promise-queue works in order to properly reason about what you 'should do'.

Comment: Maybe try adding this to the top of your code because it might be allowing both to run at the same time: `const maxConcurrent = 1;
const maxQueue = 1; const queue = new Queue(maxConcurrent, maxQueue);`

Comment: @agm1984 thanks that fixes it. that ctor variable is actually named `maxPendingPromises` in the source code which is confusing. Why this defaults to `Infinity` instead of simply `1` is beyond me. That library is called Queue that has a method called `add` that takes a function as an argument but then executes those function callbacks concurrently by default?? wtf

Comment: @agm1984 am  sure your first comment is not accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change

```
let queue = new Queue();
```

to use the concurrency parameter

```
let queue = new Queue(1);
```

then your code works as you expect

Perhaps there's a >1 default concurrency in promise-queue

> looking at [the source code](https://github.com/azproduction/promise-queue/blob/master/lib/index.js#L74), the default is `Infinity` concurrent Promises

Comment: can you explain what is the purpose of having a 'queue' that has an infinite amount of concurrent promises? i.e. what is a real world usage of such a queue ?

Comment: I have no idea why the default would be so counter intuitive